# Have any scholars believed that devas are incorporeal and bodiless?

Tags: gods, philosophy, vedanta, body, shad-darshana

I have come to believe that the devas are immaterial and not free from bodily restrictions. Were there any theologians throughout history who believed that devas are immaterial?

I believe that devas are incorporeal since they can do things that would be impossible if they were constrained by a corporeal nature.

1. Devas create the material universe which would be impossible if they were material creatures.
2. Devas can hear our thoughts even though our thoughts are soundless. This implies that they can sense without the need of bodily organs.
3. Devas are omnipresent which they could not be if they were corporeal.
4. Devas can be present in temple idols which they could not be if they were corporeal.
5. Devas can act on the world and cause miracles, without any need for a body part.

I do not find the arguments otherwise convincing, since they rely on materialism, which is false.

Comment: devas are not material in that they do not possess the outer material sheath. They have fine bodies. Black/white, material/immaterial are christian concepts and western scientifism. There are degrees, a spectrum, of materialism- it is not black and white.

Comment: So they are immaterial in comparison with us, but material in comparison with Brahman?

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda “A spectrum of materialism” <—- Thx for saying this, makes sense, and at higher levels of advanced yogis types, they can move where they wish on spectrum, in and out of form (sheaths) as far as I understand.